# facedetect.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/objdetect.hpp' file not found

Tags: opencv3.0

I just installed opencv3 on my OSX using cmake ->make->make install . Then I went to the samples/cpp folder and run this command

```
 g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv3` facedetect.cpp -o /tmp/test && /tmp/test
```

I am getting this error

```
facedetect.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/objdetect.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
```

Comment: ok I realised that even though it it opencv3. the installation was as opencv. so I replace opencv3 by opencv and I moved to next issues

Answer (score 0):

Cmake didn't work for me. I found it easier to simply install it using the whl file. I got it from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

1) Download the whl file you need (search the page for "opencv")
2) Open a terminal in the directory of the downloaded file.
3) pip install the file you downloaded
example: pip install "path/to/file/opencv_python-3.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl"

I did this and it worked for me. None of the files were missing. I don't own a mac(yet) and I'm not sure if you'll run into any problems or not, but I hope this helps.